# Is it possible to always include the VAT in a Sylius shop?

Tags: sylius

When you use Sylius, all prices displayed without taxes. In the checkout flow, you see the amount of taxes that is added.

Is there an option to activate to always include the VAT in all views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including/excluding vat into price is defined with tax.

So if you want to display prices (in public pages) with taxes:

1. Go to administration
2. Go to "Tax rates"
3. Edit tax rate, that is used with your products
4. Check "Included in price?"
5. Reset cache (app/console cache:clear --env=prod && app/console cache:clear --env=dev)